# Create bootable ubuntu usb for mac, or any pc

Tags: ubuntu, osx, live-usb

I've used Ubuntu live and the start up disk creator tool to create a bootable usb with ubuntu.

I used the start up disk tool and I first clicked erase, to clear the contents of the usb, and then create disk. It completed successfully, but I cannot get my mac to recognize it as a bootable device. It does not show up in the startup disk list (in system preferences). I cannot get it see the device using 'option' or 'c' while rebooting.

How do I get mac to see it as a bootable device?

Thanks,
-N

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options:

1. Using GParted, you can select the disk, right-click on the partition, then select "Manage Flags".  From there, tick the "boot" flag.
2. Run the command `sudo syslinux -ma /dev/sdCX`, where C is the specific mount drive of the USB drive (likely c or d), and X is the number of the partition (likely 1).